# Cannot remove folder in Snap-directory

Tags: snap

In snap directory I have folder "gradle".

But even when I'm trying to remove gradle under "root" (sudo rm -R gradle),
I receive:

```
cannot remove 'gradle/78/etc/X11/Xreset': Read-only file system

cannot remove 'gradle/78/etc/X11/Xreset.d/README': Read-only file system

....
```

Answer (score 5):

The subdirectories of `/snap` are mount-points for your snaps. All snaps are mounted read-only thus you can't edit or delete files inside them.

If you want to remove the directory `/snap/gradle` you'll have to run the proper uninstall command:

```
snap remove gradle
```

Alternatively you could disable the snap:

```
snap disable gradle
```

makes the snap unavailable on your system. With `snap enable gradle` you could then make the application available again without reinstalling it.