# How can I proceed if it is impossible to delete a (snap) readonly directory?

Tags: command-line, printing, bug-reporting, read-only

I want to execute a similar command to the following command from [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080660/631723) post

```
sudo rmdir /usr/share/ghostscript/9.25/iccprofiles
```

The actual command is

```
sudo rmdir /snap/gimp/367/usr/share/ghostscript/9.50/iccprofiles
```

When I execute the following command, I am encountering the following error:

> rmdir: failed to remove
> '/snap/gimp/367/usr/share/ghostscript/9.50/iccprofiles': Read-only
> file system

How to delete the directory?

---

From comments, I came to know that I cannot delete the file.

I asked this question inorder to make my printer work. Printer is perfectly fine, but seems there are lot of issues with OS and hence it is behaving randomly. I tried with latest version of Ubuntu as well as Linux mint. So I  read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084969/upgrade-ubuntu-16-06-lts-18-04-printer-brother-hl-l2320d-stopped-working) and then [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/924915/broken-ghostscript-configuration?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Now, I have no clue of how to proceed further. Do I need to report the issue? If yes, I am not expertise in finding the exact reason for issue such as the (wrong) file, (error)line etc.,

Comment: You can't delete a file from a snap. As it says, the snaps are read-only filesystems, designed not be modified.

Comment: @muru Then is it impossible to work according to post? And how do the users execute it?

Comment: You can manipulate whole snaps, not components of snaps, with the `snap` command. Read `man snap`.

Comment: @hanugm People who did use it probably had it installed using `apt`, not as a snap. On the plus side, snaps are easier to update for the devs, so if you file a bug report for the broken file and get it fixed, the update is will reach you quicker.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot remove folder in Snap-directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1328180/cannot-remove-folder-in-snap-directory)